# Block the Anonymous users from Artifactory Pull access using API

Tags: artifactory

Currently anyone can able to pull the artifacts from artifactory using rest api without using credentials,is there anyway to block the pull access to anonymous users to pull the artifacts using rest api without credentials?Please advise.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. Got to Admin -> Security Configuration -> General Security Configuration. Uncheck **Allow Anonymous Access** to disable anonymous access.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Security#ConfiguringSecurity-AllowAnonymousAccess